# Only read only mode on partition other than root partition

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, grub, read-only

First of all, I am new to Linux environment.

Recently I decided to switch to Linux environment to become a computer geek :P. But need to have Windows also for some basic tasks like Office and for siblings.

My choice of Linux is Elementary OS dual booting with Windows.

I installed Windows 10 (free installation, old one was years old now) and then installed Linux so I wont get into any trouble with grub and stuff.

Used Elementary fine and Windows too, no issues. And then the problem arises:

Windows gave me an update, I updated my system. Previously, I didn't got any trouble with accessing files. I used to download torrents from both distro into the same folder which was NTFS(E: drive) btw but after the update all drives are still mounted in Linux and are read only now. Another thing I notice in Grub Loader, previously there were only two options to select Elementary or Windows, now it gives me 4-5 options saying boot from F:\efi or G:\efi (something like that it shows more than one location of efi. Don't know this stuff).

**Problem is I am not able to write to any partition other than my linux partition(/), rest are mounted read-only.**

Currently, three drives are installed in my PC:

1) Drive on which Windows is installed
[image]

2) Drive on which Linux is installed

[image]

3) External Drive for storage 
[image: enter code here]

Comment: First of all disable the Fast Startup feature in Windows that was likely re-enabled by the update.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia can you guide me where to find the option to disable them. As I said it is fresh installation and I haven't disabled anything and If you saying that Linux installation disabled it and then what exactly Linux disables :)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Fast Startup!! Startup doesn't bother me. I still get option to boot from whether Windows or Linux. How exactly, fast startup affect files and folder access?

Comment: No, you misunderstood a lot.  The Fast Startup is a **Windows** feature that must be disabled in order to write to ntfs partitions from outside Windows because it causes the system not fully shutdown - it's hibernation of some sort - so to give the illusion Windows boots fast. It can only be enabled/disabled in **Windows** and some **Windows** major updates re-enable it when previously disabled.

Comment: Please google how to disable Fast Startup.